# Help me Solve unit test

Tags: apex, unit-test

>
Here is the class where i need unit test

```
public class extCtrlEx 
{

private final account acc;
public extCtrlEx(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
this.acc=(account)controller.getRecord();
}
public string getGreetings(){
return 'Hello '+acc.name ;
}
public void display(){}

}
```

> I tried unit test it populates error like Compile Error: Constructor not defined: [extCtrlEx].() plz help to resolve the issue.

```
@isTest

public class extCtrlEx_TC

{

static testMethod void testMthd()
{
Account acc=new Account();
//  extCtrlEx ece=new extCtrlEx ();

//    ece.display();

//    ece.getGreetings();

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to construct a StandardController and pass that as a parameter to the constructor for your controller. StandardController needs one parameter: the account SObject you just created.

Answer (score 0):

```
@isTest

public class extCtrlEx_TC

{

static testMethod void testMthd()
   {
      Account acc=new Account();
      ApexPages.StandardController ext =new ApexPages.StandardController(acc);
      extCtrlEx exc = new extCtrlEx(ext);

      System.assert('Add your assertion');
   }
}
```